# Is there way to get a background color when the click happen in java?

Tags: java, graphics

I want to know the background color in the spot where the mouse clicked.
For example, If I click green, I want to let my program know that I clicked green.
Is there a way to get it in java?

Comment: background color of what? If it's a component of your application, sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot API to do this, to get the color of the current mouse position you can do this

```java
int xValue = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int yValue = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color color = robot.getPixelColor(xValue, yValue);
```

Then you can compare the color and check with it, if you want the color when the user click only you need to listen for the right or left click then use the same code in the listener to get the color in this moment